# copy table rows and paste they in same table

Tags: mysql, database

I want to copy all rows from table and insert this rows in itself this table, that is if in table are rows

```
column
--------
A
B
```

I want obtain

```
column
--------
A
B
A
B
```

This may be make with php (or other language) right? but I interest, possible make this as 1 query? own mysql can this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `column` )
    SELECT `column` FROM `table`;
```